# Modifying existing xlsx file and export it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I'm trying to modify a xlsx file exixting in my project and exporting it using the roo gem but can't do it, any help please

```
def exam_grades
      file_name = 'lib/excel/exam.xlsx'
      xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_name, extension: :xlsx)

      xlsx.sheet('NotesCC').set('G', 18, 18)

      send_data file_name, type: 'application/xlsx', filename: "#{@exam.name.split.join('_')}.xlsx"
end
```

i get this error for the code above

Excel cannot open the file 'controle_N_1 (2).xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: *"Roo implements read access for all common spreadsheet types."* - Note it does not mention write access.